# Contextily add_basemap inferred zoom level is not valid and changing zoom parameter doesn't fix issue

Tags: python, geospatial, geopandas, contextily

**I want to plot the background map of Melbourne behind the plotted points of property addresses.**

I used the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import shape
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import contextily

MELB_PROPERTY_DATA = "https://data.melbourne.vic.gov.au/resource/imwx-szwr.json"

properties = pd.read_json(MELB_PROPERTY_DATA)
properties['the_geom'] = properties['the_geom'].apply(shape)
properties_geo = gpd.GeoDataFrame(properties).set_geometry('the_geom')

ax = properties_geo.plot(markersize=1)
contextily.add_basemap(ax)
plt.show()
```

At the contextily.add_basemap(ax) line I get the following UserWarning.

> contextily\tile.py:632: UserWarning: The inferred zoom level of 30 is
> not valid for the current tile provider (valid zooms: 0 - 18).

I read the [Contextily docs](https://contextily.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro_guide.html#Fine-tune-zoom-levels) but they don't fix my problem.

Changing the line to contextily.add_basemap(ax, zoom=5) removes the UserWarning but still no background map appears.
Similar questions have been asked on SO, but I can't retrofit them to my problem.

I feel like I'm importing lots of libraries for this simple task as well, so if you have any suggestions to fine-tune it that would also be appreciated.

[image: Output chart showing marks for addresses in Melbourne but with no basemap for context]

Comment: Basemap and data must be on the same projection, try `contextily.add_basemap(ax, crs=properties_geo.crs.to_string()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved this by realising from swatchai's comment that a Coordinate Reference System (CRS) was never defined.

See below for final code, with erroneous lines commented out to show the difference.

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import shape
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import contextily

MELB_PROPERTY_DATA = "https://data.melbourne.vic.gov.au/resource/imwx-szwr.json"

properties = pd.read_json(MELB_PROPERTY_DATA)
properties['the_geom'] = properties['the_geom'].apply(shape)

# properties_geo = gpd.GeoDataFrame(properties).set_geometry('the_geom')
properties_geo = gpd.GeoDataFrame(properties, geometry='the_geom', crs='EPSG:4326')

ax = properties_geo.plot(markersize=1)

# contextily.add_basemap(ax)
contextily.add_basemap(ax, crs=properties_geo.crs.to_string())

plt.show()
```