# How to put a Geopandas plot on top of a matplotlib pyplot image?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, geopandas, cartopy

At the moment, I have a plot of a certain geographic area that is coming from cartopy and I have a geometry object plotted from Geopandas, but no matter what I do I can't get them to combine into one plot.  The axes are the same for both and I can actually get the axes of the geometry object onto the geographic area, but then my shape disappears.

Here is the relevant section of code:

```
from cartopy.mpl.gridliner import LONGITUDE_FORMATTER, LATITUDE_FORMATTER
import cartopy.io.img_tiles as cimgt
import geopandas as gpd   
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt   
                
                
# Plotting the trade area graph
trade_geo_df = trade_area_response.json()['data']
trade_geo_df = gpd.GeoDataFrame(trade_geo_df)
trade_geo_df.loc[:, 'coordinates'] = trade_geo_df.coordinates.map(lambda x: x[0])
trade_geo_df['geometry'] = trade_geo_df.coordinates.apply(shapely.geometry.Polygon)
trade_geo_df['geometry'].plot()   
plt.plot(placer_lng, placer_lat, markersize=2, marker='o', color='red')  # Just a red dot

fig = plt.figure()
stamen_terrain = cimgt.Stamen('terrain-background')
        
# Limit the extent of the map to a small longitude/latitude range
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection=stamen_terrain.crs)
ax.set_extent([-89, -86, 41, 43], crs=ccrs.Geodetic())
gl = ax.gridlines(crs=ccrs.PlateCarree(), draw_labels=True, linewidth=2, color='gray', alpha=0.5, linestyle='--')
gl.ylabels_right = False
gl.xlabels_top = False
gl.xformatter = LONGITUDE_FORMATTER
gl.yformatter = LATITUDE_FORMATTER
gl.xlabel_style = {'size': 10, 'color': 'gray'}
gl.ylabel_style = {'size': 10, 'color': 'gray'}
            
ax.add_image(stamen_terrain, 8)
            
ax.plot(placer_lng, placer_lat, markersize=2, marker='o', color='red', transform=ccrs.Geodetic())  # Just another red dot
plt.show()
```

For more information, the following is the `trade_geo_df['geometry']` that is mentioned in the code block:

```
Out[4]: 
0    POLYGON ((-87.94035 41.93909, -87.93965 41.939...
1    POLYGON ((-87.88849 42.01734, -87.88676 42.016...
2    POLYGON ((-87.92825 42.02102, -87.92652 42.020...
3    POLYGON ((-87.86428 42.04548, -87.86255 42.045...
4    POLYGON ((-87.86947 42.05987, -87.86774 42.059...
5    POLYGON ((-87.87466 42.08422, -87.87293 42.084...
6    POLYGON ((-88.03025 42.10923, -88.02852 42.109...
7    POLYGON ((-88.01296 42.10972, -88.01123 42.109...
8    POLYGON ((-87.90750 42.12355, -87.90577 42.123...
9    POLYGON ((-88.01296 42.13131, -88.01123 42.130...
Name: geometry, dtype: geometry
```

And finally these are the two figures that come up.  They have the same axes and I'm just trying to get them to line up on one figure (red dot is in the same location in both, but I know there's something I'm missing.

[image: Geographic Area]

[image: Trade Area I want on top]

I've tried setting the axes for the geometry object to be the same as the geographic image, turning them into subplots of the same figure, switching the `zorder` and putting them in the same figure, etc. but nothing seems to work.  I don't have much experience with plotting so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I rearranged your lines of code to their proper places,  added/corrected projection data where necessary. The unrelevant lines are commented out. Finally, here is the resulting code that you can try.

```
from cartopy.mpl.gridliner import LONGITUDE_FORMATTER, LATITUDE_FORMATTER
import cartopy.io.img_tiles as cimgt
import geopandas as gpd   
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt  
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

stamen_terrain = cimgt.Stamen('terrain-background')
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,6), subplot_kw={'projection': stamen_terrain.crs})

ax.set_extent([-89, -86, 41, 43], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())

# Plotting the trade area graph
#trade_geo_df = trade_area_response.json()['data']
#trade_geo_df = gpd.GeoDataFrame(trade_geo_df)
#trade_geo_df.loc[:, 'coordinates'] = trade_geo_df.coordinates.map(lambda x: x[0])
#trade_geo_df['geometry'] = trade_geo_df.coordinates.apply(shapely.geometry.Polygon)
#trade_geo_df['geometry'].plot(ax=ax)   
ax.plot(-87, 42, markersize=20, marker='o', color='red', transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(), zorder=100)  # Just a red dot

gl = ax.gridlines(crs=ccrs.PlateCarree(), draw_labels=True, linewidth=2, color='gray', alpha=0.5, linestyle='--')
gl.ylabels_right = False
gl.xlabels_top = False
gl.xformatter = LONGITUDE_FORMATTER
gl.yformatter = LATITUDE_FORMATTER
gl.xlabel_style = {'size': 10, 'color': 'gray'}
gl.ylabel_style = {'size': 10, 'color': 'gray'}

ax.add_image(stamen_terrain, 8)
#ax.plot(placer_lng, placer_lat, markersize=2, marker='o', color='red', transform=ccrs.Geodetic())  # Just another red dot
plt.show()
```

Output:-

[image: redlake]

Comment: Thank you very much for the response.  May I ask why you commented out the `trade_geo_df['geometry']` though?  That brings in the polygon that I need overlaid on top of the map that you show as output.

Comment: I avoid touching the parts involving "your" data (Did you provide full access to them?). You should uncomment the commented codes and run, then tell me if it works in your environment? Note the use of .plot(ax=ax) in one of the commented line. That will plot your data on the same common map/axis. However, as I see, your data needs to set CRS to match with the basemap/plot_axis with .to_crs(stamen_terrain.crs, inplace=True). 
I hope it all go along correctly. Please give feedback soon so I and people here can help you further.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you very much.  I didn't provide full access to the parts involving the geometry though because of a paid API that is needed to retrieve it.  When I run the code with the commented out lines, I get the same output as you, but unfortunately when I uncomment them to add in the geometry the background goes away and I'm left only with a red dot on those axes and a white background instead of two figures overlaid.

Comment: I don't know what proper "etiquette" here would be but, while the above answer did not resolve my problem, I plotted things a bit differently and got it to work using another one of swatchai's comments found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65071709/contextily-add-basemap-inferred-zoom-level-is-not-valid-and-changing-zoom-parame)!  Since his answer from the past helped me, I accepted his answer here to give him credit.

Comment: @DomM In the future, when someone (including you) post a better answer, you can undo your decision here and accept that one instead. Remember no one can help you 100% without access to all necessary dependencies.

Comment: Very true, thank you.  Does it break any rules to keep the post as-is though?  Your answer on the other post solved my problem so I wanted to give you some kind of credit!

Comment: AFAIK no rule breaking. Thanks.